# MongoDB aggregate and count json paths

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB Collection which contains data elements like this:

```
{
"_id" : "9878jr23geg",
"element" : {        
    "name" : "element7",        
    "Set" : [ 
        {
            "SubListA" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "AlbertEinstein",
                    "value" : "45"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "JohnDoe",
                    "value" : "34"
                }, 

            ]
        },
        {
            "MoreNames" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "TimMcGraw",
                    "value" : "39"
                }    
            ]
        }

    ]
}


{
"_id" : "275678hfvd",
"element" : {        
    "name" : "element8",        
    "Set" : [ 
        {
            "SubListA" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "AlbertEinstein",
                    "value" : "45"
                },                    
                {
                    "name" : "JimmyKimmel",
                    "value" : "41"
                }                    
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to count the occurrences of each unique name, grouped by the element of `Set` to which they belong. For example, both objects in my example above have an object with `name: "AlbertEinstein"` inside `element.Set.SublistA`; therefore I'd expect a return value something along the lines of:

```
element.Set.SublistA.AlbertEinstein | 2
```

Essentially, I'd like a count for each of the distinct names when the data is grouped by objects within `element.Set`.

Ideally, for the example given, I'd like all of:

```
element.Set.SubListA.AlbertEinstein | 2
element.Set.SubListA.JohnDoe | 1
element.Set.MoreNames.TimMcGraw | 1
element.Set.SublistA.JimmyKimmel | 1
```

I've tried several aggregate queries but none seems to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you describe the expected outcome? What do you want to achieve? A count of how many times a person is cited? Is the Set in which they are found relevant?

Comment: I want to count all names and group by the complete path. The Set is not relevant, but the SubList can be different.